# Datatables Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am getting the following error when trying to fill a Datatable using ajax: DataTables warning: table id=employeeTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4.
The table actually has the correct number of rows, but all rows are empty. The output rows look like this:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

There are quite some answers to this issue out there, but none seems to fix my issue. The code I use is:

```
function fillEmployeeTable(store_nr,week_limit) {
  $('#employeeTable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "api/employeetable/data",
      "data": {
        "store_nr": store_nr,
        "week_limit": week_limit,
      },
      "columns": [
              { "data": "function_name" },
              { "data": "register_id" },
              { "data": "age" },
              { "data": "contract_until" },
              { "data": "worked_hours" },
              { "data": "days" },
              { "data": "costs" },
              { "data": "hourly_rate" },
              { "data": "contract_from" }
          ]
    }
  });
}
```

With the following HTML

```
<table class="table" id="employeeTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>function_name</th>
<th>register_id</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>contract_until</th>
<th >worked_hours</th>
<th>days</th>
<th>costs</th>
<th>hourly_rate</th>
<th>contract_from</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>

(document).ready(function() {
  fillEmployeeTable({{default}})
});
```

And the JSON data returned is:

```
{"data": [{"function_name": "Y", "register_id": "1", "age": 26, "contract_from": "01-07-18", "contract_until": "31-12-99", "worked_hours": 1, "days": 9, "costs": 7, "hourly_rate": 2}, {"function_name": "X", "register_id": "1", "age": 18, "contract_from": "24-01-18", "contract_until": "31-07-18", "worked_hours": 486.25, "days": 76, "costs": 1, "hourly_rate": 2}]}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: i think you missing tbody of table

Comment: In all examples I've seen you do not add the tbody in the HTML also when you inspect the page source, you see that the tbody is added by the javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've found the answer. The problem was in the way the ajax data was formatted. Although it was perfect JSON, every row should start with square brackets instead of curly brackets. So it works with { "data": [ [row1], [row2] ] }.

Comment: I'm using it with previous format of your JSON in my project. Try adding`"dataSrc": "data"` inside ajax option so DataTables will know data is an array of object instead of arrays. Like this: `ajax:{url:...,dataSrc:'data'}`

Comment: The problem in your OP code was that you not were closing the ajax section correct before columns.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions, but both did not work in my case.

Answer (score -1):

try this change in your html code...

```
<table class="table" id="employeeTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>function_name</th>
<th>register_id</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>contract_until</th>
<th >worked_hours</th>
<th>days</th>
<th>costs</th>
<th>hourly_rate</th>
<th>contract_from</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

(document).ready(function() {
  fillEmployeeTable({{default}})
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make a difference. Which makes sense, since running the JS code already adds the tbody tag.